# Does super need to be called for onViewRecycled?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I override `onViewRecycled` in `class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter`.

```
@Override
public void onViewRecycled(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {

    ...
    super.onViewRecycled(holder);
}
```

Does `super` have to be called when overriding?

#### Side note

I also wonder because I get the (well known) error when calling super:

> Unchecked call to 'onViewRecycled(VH)' as a member of raw type
> 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, because `RecyclerView.Adapter` is an [abstract class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html) and has no concrete implementation. See [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter):

[image]

Comment: Thank you, question fully answered.

Comment: You shouldn't assume that a method of an abstract class isn't implemented though.  In the case of [onViewRecycled](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:recyclerview/recyclerview/src/main/java/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.java?q=%22public%20void%20onViewRecycled%22%20file:RecyclerView.java), RecyclerView.Adapter provides a default empty implementation so that extending classes don't have to override it.  There's nothing preventing the owner of the abstract class from adding implementation (other than the desire to stay backward-compatible.)

Comment: Read my answer again. I wrote *it's abstract class AND has no default implementation", not "it has no default implementation because it's abstract class"